# All numbers of form $10^{k} + 1$ are composite for $k{\gt}2$ proof

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I have observed that all numbers of the form $10^{k} + 1$ are composite for $k{\gt}2$, and am trying to prove the same.

**Progress**

For odd $k$ , it is fairly obvious, as we get 11 as a divisor.

I am having difficulty with $k$ even. Have no clue how to approach. Would prefer a non-inductive approach, if possible

**Developments**

Thanks to crostul, we can say it is composite for $k$ having an odd divisor. Hence, it only remains to prove it for $k = 2^n$

Comment: This is pretty simple when $k$ has an odd prime divisor $p$ (as $10^{k/p}+1$ would be a divisor). However, I don't think a proof for numbers of the form $10^{2^a}+1$ exists.

Comment: This question surely is a duplicate ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem whether or not $G_n=10^{2^n}+1$ is composite for all $n\ge 3$ is open as well as the problem whether or not the Fermat numbers $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ are composite for all $n\ge 5$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number), and the article on [generalized Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Generalized_Fermat_primes).