# Is there exist some k > 1, such that $10^{2^k} + 1$ is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

After doing some numerical test, I find $10^{k} + 1$ is not prime unless k = 1, 2.
I know that If k is odd, then $11 \mid 10^{k} + 1 = (11 - 1)^k - 1$, and if k is even and not a power of 2, then using the same method, $10^{k} + 1$ is not prime. So the only case is to check whether there exist some k > 1, such that $10^{2^k} + 1$ is prime?

Comment: The equation $10^k+1=(11-1)^k-1$ is wrong. Do you mean $(11-1)^k+1$?

Comment: In fact, $11,101$ are the only known base 10 [generalized Fermat primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Generalized_Fermat_primes)

Comment: This is a duplicate of my question from many years ago... it's an open problem

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1995847/all-numbers-of-form-10k-1-are-composite-for-k-gt2-proof

Comment: Such a prime would vastly exceed the largest known prime. Probably there is no such prime, but noone knows.

Comment: The smallest unknown case is $k=31$ , see here : http://www.prothsearch.com/GFN10.html